# how do you Display a modal when a button is clicked in javascript? i need a example, thanks

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

how do you Display a modal when a button is clicked in javascript? i need a example, thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of using alert you will want to look for a modal library like https://micromodal.now.sh/ or build your own.

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
 alert("World");
})
```

```html
<button id="myButton">
Hello
</button>
```